# Geo .PDF to .tiff background colour

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I have a geo-referenced pdf that I'm transforming into .mbtiles or .tiff using

```
gdal_translate 00989I11.PDF 00989I11.tiff
```

The problem is that the result does not have a white background as I would expect. I'm a bit new to all the gdal manipulation but my question is how could I change all the transparent pixels into white pixels.

PDF looks like this. [source here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nw82o89cjew3zl/00989I11.PDF?dl=0)

[image]

The resulting .tiff looks like this [source here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3bx8gi5rd8blae/00989I11.tiff?dl=0):
[image]

The gdalinfo of the .pdf is:

```
gdalinfo 00989I11.PDF
Driver: PDF/Geospatial PDF
Files: 00989I11.PDF
Size is 806, 1237
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6269]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",35.2372777777778,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-120.642611111111,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",45,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",33,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["Inch",0.0254000508001],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["Inch",0.0254000508001],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["Inch",0.0254000508001]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["Inch",0.0254000508001]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-1807172.000000000000000,2042985.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (3334.000000000000000,-3335.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AUTHOR=
  CREATION_DATE=D:20190718071421-04'00'
  CREATOR=MicroStation 8.11.9.867 by Bentley Systems, Incorporated
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((-1487388.02470535 -1654179.3669621,563048.661741154 -1654193.12139478,563073.777508997 1615063.22966106,-1487370.34966788 1615075.17034221,-1487388.02470535 -1654179.3669621))
  PRODUCER=Adobe PDF Library 9.0
  TITLE=00989I11
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-1807172.000, 2042985.000) (121d 9' 6.29"W, 35d42'19.70"N)
Lower Left  (-1807172.000,-2082410.000) (121d 8'43.15"W, 34d45'28.56"N)
Upper Right (  880032.000, 2042985.000) (120d23'40.84"W, 35d42'22.90"N)
Lower Right (  880032.000,-2082410.000) (120d23'52.11"W, 34d45'31.72"N)
Center      ( -463570.000,  -19712.500) (120d46'20.58"W, 35d13'57.63"N)
Band 1 Block=806x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 403x619, 202x310, 101x155
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 403x619, 202x310, 101x155
Band 2 Block=806x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 403x619, 202x310, 101x155
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 403x619, 202x310, 101x155
Band 3 Block=806x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 403x619, 202x310, 101x155
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 403x619, 202x310, 101x155
Band 4 Block=806x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 403x619, 202x310, 101x155
```

Comment: what is the nodata value of your dataset? is it 255? if it is try unsetting the no data value

Comment: where can I find it and how can I change it?

Comment: if you do `gdalinfo` on your file- it will tell you what the no data value is if it is set. To unset the no data you can use `gdal_edit` command

Comment: I've updated my original post with the `gdalinfo` output but I don't see any `nodata`

Comment: that's odd -i've downloaded the images and run `gdal_translate` but I get a white background. What version of gdal are you using? I've got 2.2.3

Comment: `GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28` Installed from https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the linux version of gdal and there it works as expected with the same input files. Since I'm on mac, I will use the Docker version of gdal so the command I use is

```
docker run -ti --rm -v $(pwd):/data osgeo/gdal  gdal_translate /data/00989I11.PDF /data/00989I11.tiff
```

or for .mbtiles:

```
docker run -ti --rm -v $(pwd):/data osgeo/gdal  gdal_translate /data/00989I11.PDF /data/00989I11.mbtiles  -of mbtiles --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 30
```

And the resulting tiff does have the background color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small addendum to *gdal_translate*:

**Convert GeoPDF to GeoTIF with white background**

```
gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES -co JPEG_QUALITY=90 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 <file.pdf> <file.tif>
```

**Convert GeoPDF to GeoTIF with transparent background**

```
gdal_translate --config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 4 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES <file.pdf> <file.tif>
```

**Create overviews**

```
gdaladdo --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK YES -r cubicspline <file.tif> 2 4 8 16
```

With JPEG compression you will loose your transparency, but I guess you can use "--config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 3" with different compressions (i.e. CCITTFAX4) as well.